# Inserting data to a CLOB type in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

i have created a table

```
create table test_clob(
  value clob
);
```

if i try to do an insert on this table with the data size grater than 4000 bytes i get following error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

I don't how to use the bind variables...

Comment: How are you trying to insert the data?  What language/ API are you using to interact with the database?  Where is the data itself coming from?

Comment: well i was just experimenting it on sql developer

Comment: is there a way to do it using sql

Comment: Using plain SQL with string literals?  No, not really.  You can use PL/SQL and the `DBMS_LOB` package.

Comment: eventually i will be using it in PL-sql ,, thanks justin

Answer (score 3):

You can use **to_clob** function to insert large text  in oracle database.
Example like:String have more then 4000 char.then
use query:

insert into tableName(fieldName)values(to_clob('charCount=>4000')||to_clob('after 4000 char but not more  then 4000'));

Ex: if I have 6000 char then 4000 in first to_clob and next 2000 char next to_clob:

Answer (score 0):

**TO_CLOB** converts **NCLOB** values in a **LOB** column or other character strings to **CLOB** values. char can be any of the data types **CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB**. Here is the Oracle official documentation about [TO_CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions202.htm#SQLRF06131). To insert the data into CLOB column, use the below query.

```
insert into tableName(
    column_name
) values (
    to_clob('charCount=>4000') || to_clob('after 4000 char but not more then 4000')
);
```